# A different way to retrieve an Object in Parse with Android Studios

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

Currently I am making an Android application with Android Studios and I am using Parse to handle the data. I want to be able send (put) data such as town names and info about that town (town_names would be a column and info would be another, there for each town_names would have its own info). I can do that with ease and it uploads to the Parse database. However, the part I can not seem to figure out is how to retrieve the data points I desire. I have code to retrieve data based off of an objectId shown below however that is not exactly what I want.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("userMessage");
query.getInBackground("KgsLojXPcq", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            retrievedText = object.getString("info");
        } else {
            retrievedText = "No information.";
        }
    }
});
```

"userMessage" is the ParseObject I have created and "info" is the column I want to get text from. Instead of searching for an objectId ("KgsLojXPcq") is there a way to search for town_names? So then I could for example search the database for "New York" and "retrievedText" would be set to the info for New York.

Comment: Parse has good documentation on how to use their SDK - https://parse.com/docs/android/guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ParseQuery
    .getQuery("userMessage")
    .whereEqualTo("town_names", "New York")
    .getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                retrievedText = object.getString("info");
            } else {
                retrievedText = "No information.";
            }
        }
    });
```